# How to restore big mysql .sql backup

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

sql mysql backup when i try to restore it

```
mysql -u x -p xx < x.sql
```

method it just stucks and takes many time

is there any suggest?

Comment: Drink a tee and wait... How big is the dump?

Comment: That's probably the fastest way to do it from a SQL file.

Comment: I would recommend table level backups, as they are easier to restore.

Comment: @rekire i waited for 10 hours then slept , as i can say there is a table has 200 million records

Comment: Uhm well in that case you could drink more than one tee... ;-) You may need for such a big database a faster server. You should also stop all other access to that server to avoid deadlocks on the database. So far you need to wait...